# c++ Include files not carried over

Tags: c++, templates

I have three files:

- domain.h defines some plain structs.  one of the fields is a boost::optional
- convert.h defines template specialization that convert the plain structs to some other type.
- lib.cpp that uses domain.h and converts.h

So, the includes are:

```
//domain.h
#include <boost/optional>
//convert.h 
#include "domain.h"
#include <boost/optional>
//lib.cpp  --- version 1 does not work
#include "domain.h"
#include "convert.h"
```

The compiler(VS2010) gave a uninformative error message.  I tried adding the boost optional include:

```
//lib.cpp  --- version 2 works
#include <boost/optional>
#include "domain.h"
#include "convert.h"
```

How come the boost/optional header include wasn't carried over from domain.h and/or convert.h to lib.cpp?

EDIT:

The compiler complained it could find a template specialization for boost::optional.

I found a problem.  there's another file which defines the conversion specialization for boost::optional, convert-boost-optional.h

If I change convert.h to

```
#include "domain.h"
#include <convert-boost-optional.h>
```

then version 1 works too.  What puzzles me is how come version 2 compiles without including convert-boost-optional.h anywhere?

EDIT:
I got myself confused.  I actually included `<convert-boost-optional.h>` in lib.cpp in version 2.  Everything makes sense now.  Sorry!

Comment: `The compiler(VS2010) gave a uninformative error message.` Like... What?

Comment: The error message *was* informative, if a bit cryptic.  Please post it.

Comment: Regardless you shouldn't rely on an included file for including a header that your cpp files need - unless it is the corresponding hpp to the cpp file.

Comment: > How come the boost/optional header include wasn't carried over from
> domain.h and/or convert.h to lib.cpp? It was. Something else is going on here. Post your complete error message, we can go from there.

Comment: Kindly let *us* be the judge of the informative-level of the error message. post it please.

Comment: Can anyone delete this question?  Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing the hearder doesn't have header guards, so you could place them in your code instead:

```
#ifndef _BOOST_OPTIONAL_H_
#define _BOOST_OPTIONAL_H_
#include <boost/optional>
#endif
```

If you place this in both occasoins where you include them, you should no longer experience it.

---

But, you might wonder: **Do you actually need the include to be in the header file?**

Even if you need something from the header file in your header file, you might not need to include the header file. Learn about [forward declarations](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ForwardDeclaration) and also about [when you can't use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration).